# How do you prove Sigma Star is regular

Tags: formal-languages, regular-languages

I noticed in another answer on this forum

> Note that the languages ∅, {ϵ} and Σ* are regular.

How do you prove Sigma Star is regular.

Comment: Welcome to Computer Science! What have you tried? Where did you get stuck? We do not want to just hand you the solution; we want you to gain understanding. However, as it is we do not know what your underlying problem is, so we can not begin to help. See [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/q/1284/98) for tips on asking questions about exercise problems. If you are uncertain how to improve your question, why not ask around in [chat]?

Comment: Usually by definition. Which definition of regular languages do you have at hand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's easy to design a DFA that accepts $\Sigma^*$. Or, if your definition of regular languages is in terms of regular expressions, then the regular expression $(a_1\mid\dots\mid a_k)^*$ matches $\Sigma^*$, where $\Sigma = \{a_1, \dots, a_k\}$.